# What do you mean by particle can be in two places at once?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

Does it means that the particle (assume it has a single wave function) can show up on any 2 of infinite number of detectors at the same time? Or as hint by the single shot double slit experiment that it must have interacted with it's own clone? As far as I know there can only be 1 particle for every collapse of single wave function at any 1 time so how come it is suggested that they can be in two places at once?

Comment: In the double-slit experiment, adding a detector to only one of the paths destroys the interference pattern.  That's a big part of what is so unintuitive about it.

Comment: The particle is only _partly_ at each of those places.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the particle is only ever be detected in one place. The suggestion that a particle can be in two places at once is somewhat misleading. What it really refers to is the fact that sometimes (eg when they are detected) particles seem to behave as point-like objects, while at other times they seem to behave as waves. Waves by their nature are spread out, so it is not meaningful to speak of a wave having a position. If you drop a stone into a still pond you will cause a wave in the form of a series of concentric circular ripples- since the wave is spreading out in space it exists in multiples places at the same time.

So, while the particle is behaving in a wave-like way, its wave exists at multiple places simultaneously. Quite what that 'really' means is an unsettled question in physics. Physicists have developed different 'interpretations' of quantum theory that try to explain the effect in different ways, but there is no overall agreement as to which interpretation is right.

Comment: One interpretation is that the particle is in fact in both places at once.

Comment: Being pedantic here, but you can describe the position of a wave if the position is simply used to localize and orientate a function with a finite volume with varying mass density. This is true of all non-wave macroscopic objects as well, which differ from waves in that they don't oscillate. Speaking in terms of "two" positions doesn't make sense, as you have a continuum of positions that the wave occupies. Not sure if that's helpful to anyone.

Comment: You could define a particle as being in two places at once if its wavefunction in position space becomes multimodal. The problem then becomes that electrons in pi bonds are now in two places at once and in no rush to pick just one (quite the opposite). And the instantaneous pulse of a photon traveling through a double slit experiment is even worse, each fringe counting as a separate location.

Comment: @MattThompson Two positions makes perfect sense. If "position" is similarly "spread out". For the pedants (all of us), I can define, two positions as "the space enveloped by a pair of closed, continuous, non-overlapping surfaces".

Comment: @Aron That's a fair definition I suppose. Given that both surfaces would be defined by the same wavefunction for a single quantum particle I would probably just define it as a single non-connected position function. But, there are certainly cases where a two-position conceptualization is useful (photon passing through beam splitter and taking both discrete paths). I suppose it all boils down to semantics, as English will never be as well defined as Mathematics.

Comment: The particle can be in two places at once if there is a probability it will be at one place in contrast to another. I think the term appeared when they tried to describe where the particle was located based on probabilities. It's also called the Schrödinger equation. It is a mathematical way to predict where the particle is located, so it is not a exact result, its just an estimation based on probabilities.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Marco's answer, the wave function determines the probability of finding the particle at various locations. There are many locations where it might be found at a given time. The wave function has a non zero value at all of those locations.

The wave function also determines where the particle is likely to be next. That is,  you can calculate a future wave function from the current wave function. You need to use all of the current wave function  to calculate to each point of the future wave function. You need to use all of the places the particle might be now to find where it might be next. In this sense,  the particle acts like it is in many places at the same time.

This is different from a classical particle. If you have a probability distribution of where a classical particle might be and what its velocity might be, you would consider one possible position  and velocity at time to calculate future positions.

When the position of the particle is measured, it is always found at exactly one of the places it might be.